# How to filter by date in sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

I have a column as 'created_date' in the Database Table.

I am trying to select the record based on between two date as 'start-date' and 'end-date'

How can I write query as bellow in sphinx

> SELECT * FROM table where created_date BETWEEN "2001-01-05" AND
>   "2001-01-10"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setfilterrange](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.5/api-func-setfilterrange.html)

```
$cl->SetFilterRange ( $attribute, $min, $max, $exclude=false )
```

Here $cl is object of sphinx class, $min & max is your date range.

Hope this help !

Comment: we need to pass the date in integer format like $FromDate = strtotime('2012-01-01 00:00:00');
$ToDate  = strtotime('2012-01-21 23:59:59');
$cl->SetFilterRange ($attribute, $FromDate, $ToDate,$exclude=false);